# Using sed (?) to extract one instance of a string that is repeated in the original string

Tags: sed

INPUT:

```
<a href=FII/FOO./>FOO</a>
```

OUTPUT:

```
FOO
```

**Q:** how can I replace the INPUT with the OUTPUT? The FII and "./>" is CONSTANT. The FOO could vary to any english letter and "-" and "."

UPDATE: (to clarify "FOO")

```
FOO=ASD
then: 
<a href=FII/ASD./>ASD</a>

FOO=XYZ
<a href=FII/XYZ./>XYZ</a>
```

UPDATE2: (this one doesn't works :O )

```
[user@notebook ~] echo '<a href=FII/FOO./>FOO</a>'
<a href=FII/FOO./>FOO</a>
[user@notebook ~] echo '<a href=FII/FOO./>FOO</a>' | sed 's/>[ \t]*\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]*</\1/'
<a href=FII/FOO./FOO/a>
[user@notebook ~]
```

Comment: Which one of the two FOOs? If the slashes are what is confusing you, use something else for delimiters in the `sed` command (a comma `,` or at-sign `@` are the usual candidates, but mostly any character will do) or escape them with a backslash.

Comment: You show "FOO" twice in the input.  Which do you want to select as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the link name:

```
sed 's@^<a href[^>]*>\([^<]*\)</a>$@\1@'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee one (well-formed) tag per line, you can do:

```
sed 's/^.*>[ \t]*\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]*<.*$/\1/' your_file
```

This does not check that `FOO` is repeated as in your example. To replace only those instances of `FOO` that are repeated in the opening tag delimiter and the tag body, you can use this:

```
sed 's@< *a *href *= *FII/\([-a-zA-Z.]\+\) *\./\?> *\1 *< */ *a *>@\1@' your_file
```

The same in Perl for better readability:

```
perl -pe 's{
            < \s* a \s* href \s* = \s* FII/  # Constant part
               ([-a-zA-Z.]+)                 # Payload (saved in $1)
               \s*\./?\s*>                   # Optional space, ./ and >
               \s*\1\s*                      # Payload repeated
            <\s*/\s*a\s*>                    # Closing delimiter
           }{$1}x                            # Replace match with $1
' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks!, but I created UPDATE2 :(

Comment: @gaskopeter My bad. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want to do is to discard everything outside `href=FII/`...`./`, i would recommend something like the following (using `|` is the sed-delimiter):

```
sed -e 's|^.*href=FII/\([A-Za-z.-]*\)\./>.*$|\1|'
```

example:

```
$ echo "<a href=FII/ASD./>ASD</a>"|sed 's|^.*href=FII/\([A-Za-z.-]*\)\./>.*$|\1|'
ASD
$ echo "<a href=FII/XYZ./>XYZ</a>"|sed 's|^.*href=FII/\([A-Za-z.-]*\)\./>.*$|\1|'
XYZ
$ echo "<a href=FII/morgel.dorgel./>XYZ</a>"|sed 's|^.*href=FII/\([A-Za-z.-]*\)\./>.*$|\1|'
morgel.dorgel
```